# 'WeatherManagerDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers I'm getting this error, when I'm trying to run my code

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm getting this error on line     var delegate = WeatherManagerDelegate()

```
import Foundation
protocol WeatherManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateWeather(weather:WeatherModel)
}

struct WeatherManager {
    let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&appid=d73ab8784f3b294976fc6189b3e6eba2&units=metric"
    
    var delegate = WeatherManagerDelegate()
    
    func fetchWeather(cityName: String) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }
    func performRequest(urlString: String)
    {
        //Create URL
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            //Create a URL Session.
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            //Give session a  task
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{    //on selecting url 2nd option the seletors you get select from data                   onwards to error and press enter and it will be set to closure format.
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    /* let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
                     print(dataString!)*/
                    if let weather = parseJSON(weatherData: safeData) {
                        
                        self.delegate.didUpdateWeather(weather:weather)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Start task
            task.resume()
        }
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) ->WeatherModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodeData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            let name = decodeData.name
            let temp = decodeData.main.temp
            print(decodeData.main.temp_max)
            print(decodeData.main.temp_min)
            print(decodeData.sys.country)
            print(decodeData.weather[0].description)
            let id = decodeData.weather[0].id
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(conditionId: id, cityName: name, temperature: temp)
            print(weather.conditionName)
            print(weather.temperatureString)
            
            
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

and when I'm trying to make it an optional

var delegate = WeatherManagerDelegate?()

I'm getting this error

No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: You cannot instantiate a protocol. You need to implement a class that conforms to that protocol

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var delegate = WeatherManagerDelegate()
```

with

```
weak var delegate: WeatherManagerDelegate?
```

and update the calls to read `self.delegate?.didUpdateWeather()`

`WeatherManager` should not be responsible for creating its own delegate, that is something that should come from wherever it is begin used.

The `weak` attribute is almost always necessary when using delegates to avoid retain cycles.

Since `weak` can only be applied to class objects, you also need to indicate that in the protocol definition:

```
protocol WeatherManagerDelegate: AnyObject { ... }
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting this error, 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'WeatherManagerDelegate'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound